# error: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Werror=overflow]

Tags: c++, c

error: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Werror=overflow]

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    char ch=200;
    printf("\n%d",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

I am running this code on http://ideone.com/YNkKT6#view_edit_box and getting the implicit conversion error.
What modification do I need and what is the reason?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

n3376 3.9.1/1

> **Plain char, signed char, and unsigned char are three distinct types.** A char, a signed char, and an
> unsigned char occupy the same amount of storage and have the same alignment requirements (3.11); that is,
> they have the same object representation.

What is `char` is implementation-defined, so, you need `unsigned char` here, that handles values (0-255).

Answer (score 0):

looks like your `char` is `signed char`, which accept value from -128 to 127. and 200 is too large for it and will overflow to be a negative number.

to fix it, change `char` to `int` or `unsigned char`

```
int main()
{ 
    unsigned char ch=200;
    printf("\n%d",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `char` is **never** a `signed char`. `char` can be signed or unsigned (implementation-defined), but it's always a type distinct from both `signed char` and `unsigned char`.

Comment: This is a distinction without a difference: the behaviour of C code is in no case distinguishable from `char` being a synonym for either `signed char` or `unsigned char`. (I'm less sure about C++.)