# C: Why overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Using crappy Eclipse Nios II which uses GCC 4. Included a file, which can be found as font8x8_basic.h online . I had warnings that I was indluding the file multiple times, so I was experimenting with adding key words **const** and **extern**, having only the inclusion in main to make it global.
**extern** should not be used if an initialization is done, correct?

However, taking away **const**, gives me the warning of implicit constant conversion. Taking away **const** from the definition, doing clean, the error still remains!!?

In font8x8_basic.h

```
#ifndef FONT8x8_H_
#define FONT8x8_H_
char font8x8_basic[128][8] = {
{ 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+0000 (nul)
{ 0x00, 0x00, 0x0,...
```

In vga_util.h

```
#ifndef VGA_UTIL_H_
#define VGA_UTIL_H_
 ....
#include "font8x8_basic.h"
...
```

In sensor.h

```
#ifndef SENSOR_H_
#define SENSOR_H_
...
#include "vga_util.h"
```

In main.c

```
#include "vga_util.h"
#include "sensor.h"
```

My build log looks like this

```
05:27:22 **** Incremental Build of configuration Nios II for
project     C_eng_job4 ****
make all 
Info: Building ../C_eng_job4_bsp/
C:/altera_lite/16.0/nios2eds/bin/gnu/H-x86_64-mingw32/bin/make
--no-print-directory -C ../C_eng_job4_bsp/
[BSP build complete]
Info: Compiling main.c to obj/default/main.o
nios2-elf-gcc -xc -MP -MMD -c -I../C_eng_job4_bsp//HAL/inc
-    I../C_eng_job4_bsp/ -I../C_eng_job4_bsp//drivers/inc  -pipe -D__hal__
-DALT_NO_C_PLUS_PLUS -DALT_NO_INSTRUCTION_EMULATION -DALT_USE_SMALL_DRIVERS
-DSMALL_C_LIB -DALT_SINGLE_THREADED    -O0 -g -Wall -Wpedantic -Werror
-mno-hw-div -mno-hw-mul -mno-hw-mulx  -o obj/default/main.o main.c
In file included from vga_util.h:16:0,
             from main.c:31:
font8x8_basic.h:69:25: error: overflow in implicit constant conversion
[-  Werror=overflow]
 { 0x00, 0x66, 0x3C, 0xFF, 0x3C, 0x66, 0x00, 0x00},   // U+002A (*)
                     ^
 font8x8_basic.h:122:49: error: overflow in implicit constant conversion
[-Werror=overflow]
 { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF},   // U+005F (_)
                                             ^
cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [obj/default/main.o] Error 1
```

Complete code can be seen [here](https://github.com/karagiannis/C_eng_job2/tree/master/HW_C_engjob/HW_C_ingjob/software/C_eng_job4)

Comment: Don't learn C by trial&error! And don't use variable _definiitions_ in header files. You should consult a C book abotu what header files are and how they are intended to be used.

Comment: dont declare actual data in a header file.   Rather define the data element in the header file, in one source file declare the actual data (donlt use the modifier 'static')   Then in any other file that wants to use that data... include that header

Comment: The main question is answered in [c++ - error: overflow in implicit constant conversion \[-Werror=overflow\] - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579995/error-overflow-in-implicit-constant-conversion-werror-overflow) . Otherwise this lacks a [example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0xFF` does not fit in a `char` if it is signed.

You should use `unsigned char` for your array.

If that is not possible, then you can try to cast the value:

```
{ ..., (char) 0xFF, ... };
```

Then it should accept the number.

Also you could write the negative value. In case of 0xFF it's -1. A value between -128 and +127 will be accepted.

However, if you want that to work on any compiler, make sure to use `signed char` and not just `char` (or if you can `unsigned char`) because various compilers see `char` as signed (cl, the one you're using) and others as unsigned (gcc).

Comment: Chaned to alt_u8. Got rid of that!Thnx

Comment: But why do I still have the issue of  multiple definition of `font8x8_basic' ?

Comment: @LasseKaragiannis, it looks like tomatoRadar gave you an answer. You should not have variable declarations in your headers, only externs. Then one definition of the global in either sensor.c or main.c as you see fit.

Comment: I think you mean "You should not have variables _defined_ in your headers" , declarations are OK.

Answer (score 3):

sensor.c includes sensor.h which includes font8x8_basic.h. That gives one definition of the array font8x8_basic.

main.c includes vga_util.h which includes font8x8_basic.h. That gives one more definition of the array font8x8_basic.

Since you can have only one definition of an object in a program, you would need to make the array "extern" in the font8x8_basic.h file.

As for the compile warning since you are using initial values between 0x00 and 0xFF use unsigned char. If you want to keep the array type as char use values between -0x80 and 0x7F. Using a cast implies that you are forcing the value to meet the data type which isn't recommended.

Comment: I made a declaration in font8x8_basic.h with extern, and
did the definition in vga_util.h, but I need to access the functions of vga_util.h both in main and in sensor.c. Seems that I've built in myself in a corner. Is there a way out? See my [code](https://github.com/karagiannis/C_eng_job2/tree/master/HW_C_engjob/HW_C_ingjob/software/C_eng_job4)

Comment: always put declarations in .h files and definitions in .c files. Since you generally don't include .c files you won't run into duplicate definitions.